# Close multiple tabs which have the same base URL

Tags: firefox, browser

I have lots of tabs open. Many of them are from Amazon.com/something.

How do I close them all at once in the browser? (I'm using Firefox)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[TabCloser](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/tabcloser/) is a Firefox add-on that adds a "Close all (hostname) tabs" to the tab context menu (where (hostname) is the hostname of the selected tab).